# Remove extra space between commas in subscripts generated by InputAlias

Tags: output-formatting, input-alias

There are (unwanted) extra spaces between comma separators that are generated when I create an alias with subscript.  Here is the code I am using:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> {
    "xx" -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(\[SelectionPlaceholder], \
    \[Placeholder], \[Placeholder]\)]\)"(*subscripts*)}]
```

[image]

This problem is independent of using `\[Placeholder]`:  For example,

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases -> {
   "yy" -> "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(x, y, z\)]\)"(*subscripts*)}]
```

[image]

Any way to remove the unwanted space in the Alias?

Comment: The convention in English-base typesetting is that commas are followed by thin-spaces. Why do you want to overthrow this convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliminate the extra spaces in the alias definition:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {"xx" -> 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\),\(\[SelectionPlaceholder],\[Placeholder],\
\[Placeholder]\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {"yy" -> 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(y\), \(x,y,z\)]\)"(*subscripts*)}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove unwanted blanks by manually pasting `\[NegativeThinSpace]`.